# Post on facebook wall with official facebook app installed

Tags: android, facebook, authorization

The user of my Android app should be enabled to post a message to his facebook wall.

I used this tutorial as basis for my development:
[Link to tutorial](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/)

So far it is working fine if I have not installed the official facebook app. Thus the code uses the webview and not SSO.

But if I install the Facebook app on the same device following happens:
Pressing the "Post to facebook button" in my app opens shortly the facebook app. But it closes immediatley and returns to my app.

The only workaround I have found so far is to use Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH:

```
facebook.authorize(this.activity, this.permissions,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,new LoginDialogListener());
```

But this avoids SSO and always webview is used. There are Android apps out there which use the official facebook app and do SSO. But I searched the whole weekend for a solution without getting a clue how they are doing it.

Puting the android key hash to facebook also didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you went with the tutorial when facebook has an up to date tutorial of their own: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

The official tutorial discuss a lot of issues, including signing it so that it would work in development stage as well.  It also of course talks about authentication and the SSO, here's what you need for SSO:

```
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

And that's all.
Please, read the official tutorial and follow their instructions, it should work well.

Comment: The key hash must be from my own created key not from the androiddebugkey, right?

Comment: You don't have to have those, but you should use them, or something equivalent.. those methods persist and then load the access token which was issued for your app for the user.  Without saving that, you'll have to send the user for authentication way too often, which will resort in bad user experience. I suggest that you stop using that specific tutorial, and use the official one, along side the examples facebook provided with their android sdk (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples)

Comment: As for the key hash, follow their instructions in the **Step 5: Add your app's signature to the Facebook App Settings**. It says there that you're using androiddebugkey. This is just for development purposes.

Comment: I read this, but it seems strange to use androiddebugkey. The released version of my app is using an own key?

Comment: The signing process is not a facebook matter but an android one. Facebook just require you to update the application setting in the developer app with the hash key.  For information about that, just read [Signing in Release Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode), follow their instructions and then add the resulting key to the facebook app settings

Comment: I know how to sign my App. It is already in market. My Question is if I should use the debugkeystore to generate the key Hash for facebook. On all your links they generate the Hash via debugkeystore but this cannot be true for release version.

Comment: In that part they just explain how to sign your app, it is meant for developers who are just starting and don't know how to do so. If you already signed your app, doesn't matter how, just put the resulting key hash in the facebook application settings and it should work. They are just making sure that the key matches the one the developer added in the settings.

Comment: I am asking if I must always use the debugkeystore to create the hash for FACEBOOK or if I have to use my own keystore? As you can see they always use debugkeystore: $ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

Comment: I did answer your question, more than once, but let's try it again: No, you don't need to always use the debugkeystore to create the hash, you can use your own keystore. The only thing you have to do is to add the outcome of the signing process (the string that comes out at the end) in the application settings in the facebook developer app, where it says **Native Android App/Android Key Hash** and then you'e golden.

Comment: thx for being patient. But I still dont get my question answered. Can I use the androiddebugkeystore as used with keytool above to get the key hash STring for facebook also if I sign my app for release with my own keystore key?

Comment: You can have as many hash keys as you want, and you can generate them how ever you see fit, but each of those keys has to be added to the list in the facebook application settings. In facebook go to the Developer App, there find the facebook application you have, and edit its settings, there in the Basic tab at the bottom you have "Native Android App" add the key or keys that you have and each key you added will work for the facebook app.

Comment: ok, I know there to put the key hash String on the facebook page. But where do I have to store it in my android app? As you say I can use what ever I want for creating that key. So how does my app know this key??

Comment: I sent you to the official android tutorial for Signing in Release Mode (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode) and you said (quote): "I know how to sign my App. It is already in market". Please, make up your mind.

Comment: I have signd my android app with my own key. Otherwise it can not be on the market!  Why do you not simply answer the question: Can I create that facebook key hash with the androiddebugkey if I have signed the app with the release key?

Comment: I answered that question more than once in this corresponding, you are just missing it. If you already signed your android app then you have a key right? take that key and put it in facebook, and it should work, how is that a bad plan?

Comment: hehe. Yeah I got it that I should NOT use the debugkey. My problem is I dont know how to create the key hash for my release key. Do I have to do it this way: $ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64 by replacing the keystore?

Comment: I don't understand, you said (**twice** already) that you know how to sign your android application, and that you already have done that, if that's the case then how is it that you don't know how to create the key hash for your release???  Not to mention that it's all written in very simple way in the official android tutorial which I already linked here **twice**, but let's try again: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

Comment: because I do it via Eclipse without creating the key by my hand